# how can i show checked items of listview in next activicity in android?

Tags: android

I am New to Android. My Requirement is to check an item of list view and i want show the  selected items in next activity.

can anyone help me..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 3 things:

A XML layout that represents each row of your ListView, let's call it row.xml. It should be placed in your /res/layout folder so you can access it in Java as "R.layout.row":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <CheckBox 
            android:id="@+id/myCheckbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"/>
        <TextView 
            android:text="Hello"
            android:id="@+id/myText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The ListActivity (or regular Activity) in which you want to display the ListView:

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout);
        ArrayList<MyObjectType> data = new ArrayList<MyObjectType>();
        // Populate your data list here

        MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, data);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Then, you need to design the Custom Adapter that describes how to display the objects of type MyObjectType:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<MyObjectType> data;

    public EventAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyObjectType> data){
    // Caches the LayoutInflater for quicker use
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    // Sets the events data
    this.data= data;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.data.size();
    }

    public URL getItem(int position) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException{
        return this.data.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException{
        if(position < getCount() && position >= 0 ){
            return position;
        }
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount(){
        return 1;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        MyObjectType myObj = getItem(position);

        if(convertView == null){ // If the View is not cached
            // Inflates the Common View from XML file
            convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myText)).setText(myObj.getTextToDisplay());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

This should get you started, comment if you need more explanation.